# Flask and Apache2: No module named app

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I'm trying to deploy **Flask** app via Apache2 but I'm getting `No module named app` error. I'm also using `virtualenv`

**planer(Flask app)**

```
(venv)jdoe@jdoe-virtual-machine:/var/www/planer$ la
app.py   forms.py   .git        helpers.py   __init__.py  main.pyc   models.pyc   README.md         setup.cfg  templates  views.py
app.pyc  forms.pyc  .gitignore  helpers.pyc  main.py      models.py  planer.wsgi  requirements.txt  static     venv       views.pyc
```

**planer.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName planer.dev
        ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/planer/planer.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/planer/planer/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/planer/static
        <Directory /var/www/planer/static/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**planer.wsgi**

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert (0,'/var/www/planer')

    sys.path = [
        '/var/www/planer/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
        '/usr/lib/python2.7',
    ]

    activate_this = '/var/www/planer/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
    execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

    import app as application
```

**error**

```
[Wed Jan 06 09:45:29.781102 2016] [:error] [pid 20727] [client 127.0.0.1:42448] mod_wsgi (pid=20727): Target WSGI script '/var/www/planer/planer.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Jan 06 09:45:29.781137 2016] [:error] [pid 20727] [client 127.0.0.1:42448] mod_wsgi (pid=20727): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/planer/planer.wsgi'.
[Wed Jan 06 09:45:29.781208 2016] [:error] [pid 20727] [client 127.0.0.1:42448] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jan 06 09:45:29.781235 2016] [:error] [pid 20727] [client 127.0.0.1:42448]   File "/var/www/planer/planer.wsgi", line 12, in <module>
[Wed Jan 06 09:45:29.781302 2016] [:error] [pid 20727] [client 127.0.0.1:42448]     import app as application
[Wed Jan 06 09:45:29.781327 2016] [:error] [pid 20727] [client 127.0.0.1:42448] ImportError: No module named app
```

Comment: in `planer.wsgi`, use `from app import app as application` works?

Comment: Delete all the *.pyc and try `from planer.app import app as application` works? If still not work, you may show us the content of `app.py` and `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the .wsgi file is executable:

```
sudo chmod a+x planer.wsgi
```

And try to load it with this:

```
python /absolute/path/to/planer.wsgi
```

Comment: What happens when you do python /absolute/path/to/planer.wsgi?

Comment: @intelis what was the problem?